# Android: Padding specified in styles.xml not showing in programmatically added TextView?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am programmatically adding a `TextView` to my app's UI and making it have a small padding, based on a configuration in `styles.xml`. However, when I run my app, the `TextView` has no padding:

[image]

This seems strange, considering that I believe I have defined the padding in my `styles.xml` configuration and set it programmatically in my `MainActivity.java` correctly. Below is my code:

**styles.xml**:

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <!-- Message alerting the user that the app has not finished scraping the schedule -->
    <style name="NotDoneScrapingMsg" parent="@android:style/Widget.TextView">
        <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
        <item name="android:paddingLeft">7dp</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

**activity_main.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/baseLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**MainActivity.kt**:

```
package com.example.addtextviewwithpadding

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.LinearLayout
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.core.widget.TextViewCompat

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val baseLayout: LinearLayout = findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.baseLayout)

        // Create and add a TextView telling the user that the app is still retrieving the schedule
        val notDoneScrapingMsg = TextView(applicationContext)
        notDoneScrapingMsg.text = "Test Padding"
        //valueTV.id = 5
        notDoneScrapingMsg.layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        )
        TextViewCompat.setTextAppearance(notDoneScrapingMsg, R.style.NotDoneScrapingMsg)

        baseLayout.addView(notDoneScrapingMsg)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setTextAppearance()` on supports setting a handful of attributes and padding is not one of them. See https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable#TextAppearance

To apply a style programmatically you can use `ContextThemeWrapper` to wrap the `Context`. Also note that you should use an activity context and not the application context there. Or you can just set the padding programmatically.

Answer (score -1):

Try this following code,

```
        val notDoneScrapingMsg = TextView(applicationContext)
        notDoneScrapingMsg.setTextAppearance(R.style.NotDoneScrapingMsg)
```